# Difference between k8s /metrics endpoint in Kubelet vs APIServer

Tags: kubernetes, metrics

I am trying to understand the difference between the metrics returned from the `/metrics` endpoint on the API Server vs Kubelet.

Both seem to return similar metrics, however the apiserver has metrics for Etcd which are missing on Kubelet which makes sense.

However, I am not sure if the Kubelet `/metrics` endpoint is actually pulling its info from the apiserver or if its the other way around? Or perhaps each maintains its own set of metrics?